# Como selecionar o conteúdo do campo ao receber focus?

Tags: html5, angularjs, input

Estou com um problema que parece ser simples, mas que já me tomou bastante tempo procurando possíveis soluções e até agora não consegui resolver.

Preciso selecionar o conteúdo de um Input em um formulário HTML com Bootstrap ao receber focus.

Por padrão o HTML5 já seleciona o conteúdo do campo ao receber focus, porém eu estou utilizando uma diretiva do angularJS( ng-currency ) para formatar casas decimais, e depois da adição da diretiva, não seleciona mais.

Resumindo...

> O que quero ?
>
> Bom uma imagem vale mais do que mil palavras, ao receber focus(tab por exemplo) quero que o conteúdo do input fique todo selecionado na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> O que já tentei fazer?

Consegui fazer no evento do clique dentro do campo, dessa forma:

```
<input type="text"
   class="col-sm-12 form-control"
   ng-model="campo"
   ng-currency currency-symbol=""
   ng-click="selectAllClick($event)">

$scope.selectAllClick = function ($event) {
   $event.target.select();
}
```

Mas preciso no evento do focus, já tentei utilizar ng-focus para chamar essa função, mas não funciona.

A diretiva que estou usando é essa:
 https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency

O problema que ocorre é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Já tentou `onclick="this.select()" ` ?

Comment: Ja tentei sim, no onclick funciona, mas no onfocus não.

Comment: Tentei usar assim, vi aqui no fórum: onfocus="this.select();"                                          onmouseup="return false;", mas também não resolveu

Comment: no teste que eu fiz aqui usando esse mesmo código funcionou normal, até mesmo usando o tab, estranho, vou tentar outra coisa aqui

Comment: Então, pra mim só funciona se eu clicar dentro do campo, ou se tirar o ng-currency do input, aí funciona certinho.

Comment: Bom, a única coisa que muda é que tenho esse input dentro de uma table, mas mesmo testando fora dela, também não funciona.

Comment: Você quer que selecione ao passar o mouse por cima?

Comment: Não, ao entrar no campo, via tab é o que preciso.

Comment: Eu atualizei com a imagem de como acontece atualmente, ao entrar no campo ele joga o | para o último elemento, e eu quero que venha selecionado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38574/discussion-between-victor-gomes-and-geferson).

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" class="col-sm-12 form-control"ng-model="campo"ng-currency currency-symbol="" onClick="this.focus();this.select()"/>`

tenta assim que vai da certo, fiquei muito tempo tentando encontrar a solução.